# Two tables in one Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have 2 database tables (MSSQL SERVER) which are CM (Name of Table 1) and REM (Name of Table 2). Is it possible to make it in Crystal Reports just like in the below image?

[image: sample display ex in crystal report]

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to SO! Though your question is understandable it would have been nice if you would have tried doing it first. The answer to this is **Yes**. Now DIY and [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you face any troubles with it

Comment: tried it using sub report but it cannot be shown like what i have posted here

Comment: Then post the code to let the community know what you have done till now to assist your question. So that a solution can be worked for the same. Just edit the question and paste the codes

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is there any link between two table??? any common field for joins

Comment: Sorry about that sir halfer just newbie here its my first post actually
@Mahendra the control # is the link

Answer (score 1):

Using subreports does not gives you the ability you to use common columns, so you must figure out how to use ONE select statement from database to report.

From your snapshot it seems that your tables have 6 common columns (Control,ClientName,DateReceived,RequiredDocs,UploadStatus,Remarks) which you wish to show, and the first 3 of them are used for grouping. So you could use UNION between two SELECT of these 6 columns of your two tables and then implement the grouping in your report designer.

e.g

```
"SELECT 
Control,ClientName,DateReceived,RequiredDocs,UploadStatus,Remarks
FROM CM
UNION
SELECT 
Control,ClientName,DateReceived,RequiredDocs,UploadStatus,Remarks
FROM REM"
```

Comment: You are welcome. Set my answer as accepted if you wish, so as other users get advised from it too in the future